# Trying to install powershellempire on Kali Linux but getting a lot of error in pip.I think its a broken module lib has no attribute ERRload RANDstring

Tags: python-3.x, linux, powershell, easy-install, lib

I am showing you here, step by step, what I did.

First, I install:

```
apt install powershell-empire starkiller
```

It successfully installed. But When I try to run with the server, I receive this error:

```
> powershell-empire server
 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/powershell-empire/empire.py", line 11, in <module>
    import empire.server.server as server
  File "/usr/share/powershell-empire/empire/server/server.py", line 40, in <module>
    from empire.server.common import empire, helpers
  File "/usr/share/powershell-empire/empire/server/common/empire.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pydispatch import dispatcher
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydispatch'
```

I tried to search for this, but it brought up another error.

```
sudo python -m easy_install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
/usr/bin/python: No module named easy_install
```

```
pip uninstall pyopenssl
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named easy_install
```

I also tried with python3:

```
sudo python3 -m easy_install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named easy_install
```

```
pip2 uninstall pyopenssl
/usr/bin/python: No module named easy_install
```

Nothing worked, so I try to find solution for easy install

```
python -m pip install requests
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 169, in <module>
    _lib.ERR_load_RAND_strings()
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'ERR_load_RAND_strings'
```

Back to the first error. This mistake loops. My opensshl lib error comes first, followed by an easy install, and then it comes back. Lib Lib

One more thing is I even not able to show version of pip or pip3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six, urllib3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 46, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 169, in <module>
    _lib.ERR_load_RAND_strings()
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'ERR_load_RAND_strings'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.